# Upper bound on the magnitude of eigenvalue of a stochastic matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains, stochastic-matrices

What is the upper bound for the magnitude of the second largest eigenvalue of the following square matrix $X$ of size $d\times d$?

The entries are given as:

1. $X[0,0] = \alpha \in (0,1/d]$, $X[0, d-1] = (1-\alpha)$
2. $X[i,i-1] = 1$ for all $i\in \{1,\dots, d-1\}$
3. All other enteries are $0$.

I am interested in the case when $\alpha \sim 0$. Bounds uniformly over the state space $d >1$ is preferred.

**Relation to a Markov Chain**:
The above matrix is a transition matrix for the Markov chain (irreducible and aperiodic) with state $s\in \{0,\dots, d-1\}$.

From state $0$ with probability $\alpha$ the chain remains in state $0$, o/w it moves to state $d-1$.
For any other state $i > 0$, the chain moves to state $(i-1)$.

I am interested in the convergence rate of the Markov chain.

Comment: I assume you want a bound in magnitude? There is no guarantee that the eigenvalues are even real, much less positive.

Comment: Also, are you interested in either of the regimes $\alpha \sim 0$ or $\alpha \sim 1$? Or the regime of large $d$?

Comment: I am interested in magnitude, $\alpha \sim 0$. I am trying to make the bound work uniformly in $d$. Corrected the descriptions.

Comment: In the regime $\alpha \sim 0$ the process is a small perturbation of a deterministic cycle, so I don't see why you should expect a bound that doesn't depend on $d$.

Comment: Actually in the regime $\alpha \sim 0$ I think you can get an estimate, albeit not a rigorous bound necessarily, by just using perturbation theory starting from the known eigenvalues of the deterministic cycle, which are just the roots of unity.

Comment: Indeed see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.00785.pdf whose Theorem 1 is readily applicable here to give first order estimates of the perturbed eigenvalues for small $\alpha$, since the deterministic cycle admits a rigorous analysis.

Comment: Yeah, for each eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ with associated right eigenvector $x_i$ and left eigenvector $y_i$, scaled such that $y_i^* x_i=1$, you have that $\frac{d\lambda_i}{d\alpha}$ at $\alpha=0$ is $\overline{y}_{i,1}(x_{i,1}-x_{i,n})$. That gives an asymptotic lower bound on $|\lambda_i|$, since $|\lambda_i|=1$ when $\alpha=0$. It also gives an asymptotic upper bound, but that upper bound is useless, since it is weaker than what Gerschgorin gives you already.

Comment: Using thoery of conductance on Graphs, related to Mixing time of Markov chains I can get an upper bound of the form $(1-c\alpha^2)$. I was wondering if I can get something like $(1-c’ \alpha)$ instead.

Comment: If you mean uniformly in $d$, I highly doubt that a bound of $(1-c\alpha)$ with $c$ independent of $d$ holds. Actually I think what I said already tells you that it doesn't, because all components of the eigenvectors of the deterministic cycle have the same magnitude, so $\frac{d\lambda_i}{d\alpha}$ should go to zero as $d \to \infty$.

Comment: Also my numerics suggest that you bound with $\alpha^2$ probably doesn't hold as $d \to \infty$...with $\alpha=10^{-3}$ I find $d=10,1-|\lambda_2| \sim 10^{-5},d=100,1-|\lambda_2| \sim 10^{-8},d=1000,1-|\lambda_2| \sim 10^{-11}$.

Comment: Your matrix has a standard name -- it is called a Residual Life matrix.  This has a well known left and right steady state vectors as well as other features.  It is also (up to graph isomorphism) a Companion matrix, so you can read the characteristic polynomial off the top line.

Comment: I see. That implies it is hard to make the perturbation approach work. I feel, in this case the conductance method gives us better bounds compared to the perturbation approach.

Comment: Knowing the standard name helps a lot. Thanks @user8675309!

Comment: Any reference on the residual life matrix? @user8675309

Comment: It shows up all over the place because it exists in some sense to show the residual life  (or residual waiting times) for a renewal process defined on the positive integers.  If you own Feller vol 1 3rd edition, you'll see it on page 381.  Closely related is the chain associated with the Age of a renewal process (page 382).  If you transpose the latter and effect a similarity transform using diagonal matrix $D$ (containing steady state probabilities for latter chain) you actually recover the former chain.  This doesn't change spectrum, so you can  research chains for Age and Residual Life.